# Mock var property using mockk in android

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-testing, mockk

I have a Kotlin class:

```kotlin
class Car {
    var lights: Int = 5

    fun getAllLights(): Int {
        return lights + 2
    }
}
```

And have testing class:

```kotlin
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.spyk
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class CarTest {
    private lateinit var car: Car

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        car = spyk(Car())
    }

    @Test
    fun `test lights`() {

        every { car.lights } returns 20

        val lights = car.getAllLights()

        Assert.assertEquals(20 + 2, lights)
    }
}
```

This test is failing with error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<22> but was:<7>
> at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
> at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
> at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
> at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)

Mean `lights` is not getting mocked.

While if `light` would be `val` instead of `var` this test case would pass.

Please help in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it doesn't make sense for you to use `every { car.lights } returns 20`.

You just need to mock a value in a **public property**, which already has a **default value** and will be checked later on `Assert.assertEquals`.

My suggestion is to set the property value directly in your test object `car.lights = 20`:

```
class CarTest {
    @MockK
    private lateinit var car: Car

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        car = spyk(Car())
    }

    @Test
    fun `test lights`() {
        car.lights = 20
        val lights = car.getAllLights()
        Assert.assertEquals(20 + 2, lights)
    }

    class Car {
        var lights: Int = 5
        fun getAllLights(): Int {
            return lights.plus(2)
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you really want use `every { ... }` try to use `private` property with getter and mock it:

```
class CarTest {
    @MockK
    private lateinit var car: Car

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        car = spyk(Car())
    }

    @Test
    fun `test lights`() {
        every { car.getLights() } returns 20
        val lights = car.getAllLights()
        Assert.assertEquals(20 + 2, lights)
    }

    class Car {
        private var lights: Int = 5
        fun getLights(): Int {
            return lights;
        }

        fun getAllLights(): Int {
            return this.getLights().plus(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is not making ```every { car.lights } returns 20```

Comment: @AnkurSamarya You are trying to mock a property directly and it won't work. You can mock the method that handles this property. See edit to use mock with `every`.